# Search the fields in Database

Tags: database, search

What is the best way for searching the fields **AT THE MOMENT** in database with angularjs?

I have a JSON inside a field of database...

I want, when a user fill a text box (TextBox1), in exact time, it search at the moment inside my database. if that entire text was equal with any field of a table, fill another textbox(TextBox2) automatically.

With below code, i can fill it. and it works properly. but i thinks its not logical. Because it reads all of my data in mentioned Table first

```
   $scope.showFullName = function(){
   $scope.Fullname="";
   if($scope.MembersNationalCode.length == 10) {
   for (var i = 0; i < $scope.NaturalMembers.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.NaturalMembers[i].NationalNumber == $scope.MembersNationalCode) {
          $scope.Fullname = $scope.NaturalMembers[i].Name + " " + $scope.NaturalMembers[i].Family;
          }
      }
  }
  };
```

I'm mentioning again. It works properly. But i'm looking for best way. And this question is a sample.

Thanks.